# How to change second column in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a file with below data. I want change the second column from `"201710110923"` format to `"2017-10-11 09:23:00"` format using shell script

```
"2017-10-16  14:03:07", "201710110923"
"2017-10-16  14:03:22", "201710110930"
```

Please help.

Thanks & Regards
Rajesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
sed -r 's/(.*, \")([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})/\1\2-\3-\4 \5:\6:00/g' inputfile.in
```

Here, we are making use of regex groups to capture the matches and then replace the output. If you want to update the file, use the `-i` option.

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk -F"\"" '{$4=substr($4,1,4)"-"substr($4,5,2)"-"substr($4,7,2) " " substr($4,9,2)":"substr($4,11,2)":"substr($4,13,2)} 1' OFS="\""  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
"2017-10-16  14:03:07", "2017-10-11 09:23:"
"2017-10-16  14:03:22", "2017-10-11 09:30:"
```

Answer (score 0):

**`bash`** alternative solution:

```
IFS=','; while read d1 d2; do 
    d2=$(tr -d '[:space:]' <<<"$d2")
    new_d=$(date -d"$(echo ${d2:1:4}/${d2:5:2}/${d2:7:2} ${d2:9:4})" +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    printf '%s, "%s"\n' "$d1" "$new_d"
done < yourfile
```

The output:

```
"2017-10-16  14:03:07", "2017-10-11 09:23:00"
"2017-10-16  14:03:22", "2017-10-11 09:30:00"
```